# How to Enable Homescreen Mode from Intent URL String?

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, android-intent, mobile-chrome

We've developed a .NET web app in Chrome and we are trying to open that web app in homescreen/fullscreen mode from a mobile device management lockdown screen. We are able to successfully open the URL in Chrome using the following syntax:

```
Intent://<URL>/#Intent;scheme=https;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;component=com.android.chrome;end
```

However, this does not open the app in homescreen/fullscreen mode. Is there an easy to modify this url string to open it in homescreen mode every time? Or is there something we need to do within our .NET project to code for it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.